# JavaScript Chart Animations

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For this code I would like to be able to select a year from a checkbox and a line is drawn on the chart, and when I unselected the year, I would like the line to disappear. Is there a way to do that with the code I provided below?

```
if (trends.length == 0)

                return;

            window.seriesOptions = [];
            window.navData = [];
            var yAxisOptions = [],
                seriesCounter = 0,
                colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

            $.each(trends, function (i, trend) {

                //series creation
                $.getJSON(trend, function (data) {

                    //first line is dashed
                    if (i == 0) {
                        seriesOptions[i] = {
                            name: years[i],
                            data: data,
                            //dashStyle: 'dash',
                            lineWidth: 4,
                            color: '#000000',
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 2
                            }
                        };
                        $('')
                    }
                    else if (i > 5) {
                        seriesOptions[i] = {
                            name: years[i],
                            data: data,
                            dashStyle: 'dashdot',
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 2
                            }
                        };
                    }
                    else {
                        seriesOptions[i] = {
                            name: years[i],
                            data: data,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 2
                            }
                        };
                    }
                    navData = navData.concat(data);

                    // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
                    // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
                    seriesCounter++;

                    if (seriesCounter == trends.length) {
                        createChart();
                    }
                });
            });

            // create the chart when all data is loaded



            function createChart() {
                window.chartwidth = $('#ChartContainer').width();
                window.chartops = {
                    chart: {
                        reflow: true,
                        //marginRight: 160
                        events: {
                            load: function () {
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.imageAbsoluteRef))
                                    {
                                        WriteLiteral("this.renderer.image('" + ViewBag.imageAbsoluteRef + "', 80, 70, 100, 100).add();\n");
                                        //WriteLiteral("setChart(" + ViewBag.annot + ");\n");
                                    }
                            }
                            //redraw: function () {
                            //    var div = $('#ChartContainer');
                            //    var width = div.width();
                            //    var height = width / 1.618;

                            //    div.css('height', height);
                            //}


                        }


                    },
                    credits: {
                        text: "ClearMarketView.com",
                        href: "http://clearmarketview.com"
                    },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 4
                    },

                    colors: ['#0000FF', '#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#820082', '#008282'],

                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        align: "right",
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        y: 100,
                        floating: false,
                        @if(ViewBag.sprd == "1I")
                        {
                            base.WriteLiteral("x: -40,\n labelFormat: '<span style=\"color:{color}\">{name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b>',\n");
                        }
                        else if(ViewBag.sprd == "1S")
                        {
                            base.WriteLiteral("x: -10,\n labelFormat: '<span style=\"color:{color}\">{name}</span>: <b>{point.y: .2f} </b>',\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            base.WriteLiteral("labelFormat: '<span style=\"color:{color}\">{name}</span>: <b>{point.y: .2f} </b>',\n");
                        }
                        //itemStyle: {
                        //    align: 'right'
                        //},
                        enabled: true
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        offset: 36,
                        opposite: true
                    },
                    //xAxis:{
                    //    max: (new Date(+new Date() + 631152e5))
                    //},
                    title: {
                        text: '@ViewBag.chartTitle',
                        style: {
                            color: '#000000',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            fontSize: '18px'
                        }
                    },
                    navigator: {

                        series: {
                            name: 'base',
                            data: window.navData
                        },
                        baseSeries: 'base'
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        //pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                        //valueDecimals: 2
                        positioner: function () {

                            return {x:window.chartwidth - 100, y:75};
                        },
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e', new Date(this.x));
                        }
                    },

                    series: window.seriesOptions
                };



                $('#ChartContainer').highcharts('StockChart', window.chartops);
            }          
        });
```

Comment: How are we supposed to be able to figure this out, there's no way for us to replicate this with the ajax calls and Highcharts etc. We don't even know what lines you're talking about ?

Comment: I'm guessing it would be something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/series-show-hide/, do I edit the line for range selector? And I have check boxes instead of a button.